# How to write a setevn/export script that will work in both csh and bash?

Tags: bash, csh

In my environment (RHEL)  I have a bunch of script that are written in either csh or bash.

Some of them are used to deal with a tomcat server.

I want to keep the definitions of CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE in one place, such that csh and bash script can source  the variables from one single file.

I am more familiar with bash, and has very limited exposure to csh. So for the bash scripts it is what I will do:

```
. ~/tomcat.settings
```

And in tomcat.settings, I will have

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/mnt/apps/tomcat/6.0.20/linux
export CATALINA_BASE=/home/app1/server
```

How can I source from the same file in csh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't try to make the same script portable between two *completely different* shells. Even compatibility of sh and bash is hard to achieve, and those use the same syntax... (I can't even imagine how one can stand csh in the first place.)

---

Write your settings scriptlet like this:

```
test "$?BASH_VERSION" = "0" || eval 'setenv() { export "$1=$2"; }'

setenv CATALINA_HOME "/mnt/apps/tomcat/6.0.20/linux"
setenv CATALINA_BASE "/home/app1/server"
```

I tested this in bash 4.2.20, tcsh 6.17 and dash 0.5.7.

---

Somewhat more sane solutions:

You could keep the settings as plain text, like this:

- `~/tomcat/catalina-home`

  ```
  /mnt/apps/tomcat/6.0.20/linux
  ```
- your bash scripts

  ```
  export CATALINA_HOME=$(< ~/tomcat/catalina-home)
  export CATALINA_BASE=$(< ~/tomcat/catalina-base)
  ```
- your csh scripts

  ```
  setenv CATALINA_HOME "`cat ~/tomcat/catalina-home`"
  setenv CATALINA_BASE "`cat ~/tomcat/catalina-base`"
  ```

You could write a wrapper that would set up the environment:

- `/usr/bin/tcat`

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  # you can use any, *any* language for this one
  export CATALINA_HOME=/mnt/apps/tomcat/6.0.20/linux
  export CATALINA_BASE=/home/app1/server
  exec "$@"
  ```
- if you had `myscript`, you'd run it like `tcat myscript args args args`

You could combine the above two approaches by setting up an "env directory" containing the raw data and running your script via [Dan Bernstein's `envdir`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/envdir.html) or [Gerrit Pape's `chpst`](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html):

- ```
  echo "/mnt/apps/tomcat/6.0.20/linux" > ~/tomcat-envdir/CATALINA_HOME
  echo "/home/app1/server" > ~/tomcat-envdir/CATALINA_BASE
  ```

  ```
  envdir ~/tomcat-envdir/ myscript
  ```

  ```
  chpst -e ~/tomcat-envdir/ myscript
  ```