# Implement the "for loop" code that should work from csh/bash. The "for loop" code part is DON'T CARE when sourced from bash script

Tags: bash, shell, script

My project environment has both the csh and bash scripts

There is a csh script (say c.csh) sourced from other csh and bash scripts and c.csh currently has just few setenvs and I got the setenv working from both csh/bash scripts using the solution from the following post.

[How to write a setevn/export script that will work in both csh and bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/373962/how-to-write-a-setevn-export-script-that-will-work-in-both-csh-and-bash)

c.csh

```
test "$?BASH_VERSION" = "0" || eval 'setenv() { export "$1=$2"; }' 

    setenv MY_PROJ_BASE /home/test1
    ....
    ...
    setenv MY_ENV_FILE /test2/log
```

`MY_ENV_FILE` has the environment variables and now I need to unset each variable similar to following.

c.csh

```
setenv MY_PROJ_BASE /home/test1
..........
........
setenv MY_ENV_FILE /test2/log
.........
........
foreach ev ("`cat $(MY_PROJ_BASE)/$(MY_ENV_FILE)`")
   unsetenv $ev
end
```

The above code would throw error when sourced from bash scripts. The forloop code is  only required when sourced from csh scripts and not needed (DON'T CARE) when sourced from bash scripts.

I tried to use eval similar to setenv but couldn't get it working.

```
 test "$?BASH_VERSION" = "0" || eval 'foreach() do_something_to_work'
```

Comment: Why not just set a variable after that check to indicate whenever you're running within bash or csh and act depending on that?

Comment: Useful comparison table http://joelinoff.com/blog/?page_id=235#tbl

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, `awk` command does the trick

```
test "$?BASH_VERSION" = "0" && eval `awk 'BEGIN { str="unsetenv "} {print str$1}' $MY_ENV_FILE
```